# Dynamic html table

Tags: html, jsp, dynamic, html-table

I've to create a dynamic html table using the values configured in a table. I'm using JSP with MVC architecture.

I've a row number, column number and value fields in table. If the values are 1,5 and HELLO correspondingly, then I've to display this HELLO in row 1 and column 5.

The table structure is like the following.

```
row column   value
 1     5     value1
 2     8     value2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What dynamic web technology are you using? php? asp? asp.net (c#/vb)?

Comment: You should have tagged that as well. I added it in. With tags you reach the right audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to collect the data in a `String[][]` first:

```
int rows = getMaxRowNumberFromDB();
int cols = getMaxColNumberFromDB();
String[][] values = new String[rows][cols];

// ...

while (resultSet.next()) {
    int row = resultSet.getInt("row");
    int col = resultSet.getInt("col");
    String value = resultSet.getString("value");
    values[row][col] = value;
}
```

(note that array indexes are zero based, you may want to substract 1 from `row` and `col` first)

Then display it using [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) `c:forEach` (or any data iterating tag your "MVC architecture" thing is using) in JSP:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${values}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${row}" var="value">
                <td>${value}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the maximum column number:

```
SELECT MAX(column) AS max_column
  FROM xxx
```

Then fetch the data in row/column order:

```
SELECT *
  FROM xxx
 ORDER BY row, column
```

Then write an outer loop that iterates indefinitely, generating rows, and an inner loop that iterates over column numbers. For each cell, check whether the current result record matches the coordinates. If it does, output it and fetch the next record.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
max_column = SELECT MAX(column) ...
data = SELECT * ...
if data.eof(): exit
output "<table>"
for row = 1..∞:
    output "<tr>"
    for col = 1..max_column:
        output "<td>"
        if data["row"] = row and data["column"] = col:
            output data["value"]
            data.next()
            if data.eof(): exit
        output "</td>"
    output "</tr>"
output "</table>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Going on your limited information (i'll edit this once you give more details):

use place holders:

for each cell insert '{rol,col}'

Use sql to return :

```
 id = {rolw,col}
 value = value
```

pseudo sql:

```
select  '{'+str(row)+','+str(col)+'}' as [id]
       ,value
from    table
```

then simply loop through each record, and replace the placeholders.

**EG**